In YAML Azure Pipeline, mapping and accessing a network share doesn't work properly when running the job in a container provided by ADO agents
I am trying to run my pipeline in containers, I am using the inbuilt support that azure pipelines provide to run the jobs in containers via azure agents.
This is how my YAML looks:
resources:
  containers:
  - container: myContainerResource
    image: myregistry/image
    endpoint: 'azuredevops-service-connection'
    volumes:
    - 'C:\X:C:\X'
    - 'C:\Y:C:\Y'

stages:
- stage: 
  jobs:
  - job:
    pool:
      name: myPool
    container: myContainerResource

    steps:

    - powershell: |   # First Powershell task
        whoami   # This is printed as 'user manager\containeradministrator'

        net use \\share-path\folder1$ /user:$env:ACCOUNT $env:PASSWORD

        if (Test-Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue \\share-path\folder1$)
        {
            Write-Host "Mapping \\mr-fs01\midas$ finished successfully"  # This is executed
        }
        else
        {
          Write-Host "Mapping failed"
          exit 1
        }
        
        gc \\share-path\folder1$\myFile.txt  # The content of the file is accessible and printed
      env:
        ACCOUNT: $(USER_SECRET_FROM_VAR_GROUP_KEY_VAULT)
        PASSWORD: $(PWD_SECRET_FROM_VAR_GROUP_KEY_VAULT)
     
    - powershell: |        # Second Powershell task     
        whoami            
        gc \\share-path\folder1$\myFile.txt  # HERE THE SAME PATH IS NOT ACCESSIBLE, TROWS EXCEPTION

The 'net use' command executes properly in the first PowerShell task, and the files are also accessible. When I try to access the share or the files from the second PowerShell task, it throws exception as:
user manager\containeradministrator
gc : Access is denied
At C:\__w\_temp\0sdsd3-wewe-4d92234-2-xcxc3232.ps1:5 char:1
+ gc \\share-path\folder1$\myFile.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\share-path\folder1$\myFile.txt:Stri 
   ng) [Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.Powe 
   rShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Yes, I'm aware that it's possible to map the share as a volume, which can be used with my containers. However, my tests have hardcoded paths to the network share paths. Thus, I can't use the Docker volumes approach in this case. How can I make the second task access the network share that was perfectly mapped in the first task?

If you run this script in the container on that agent machine mannual, will the error be reproduced, or it only occurs in pipeline agent job？

If I manually run the container with the same parameters and then execute the above commands using "docker exec," it works. It only fails when run within the pipeline agent job mentioned above.

Hi @osim_ans, if you add net use as well in the second PowerShell script before gc, will the issue persists?

Then the issue won't appear. But my next task could be a VsTest task where the tests will be executed, which will try to access that network path. So, how can I solve this in non-PowerShell tasks like VsTest?

May I know how would you use the file under share-path with VSTest, like to test the assemblies there or output the test results into the share-path?

Test assemblies are in a local path, but the tests are written in a way that they access some dependencies from a hardcoded network share path. This means that when the network path is not mapped, they fail, and when mapped, they succeed. (In short, the network paths are hardcoded in the tests logic.) Thus, I'm not providing anything in the VsTest task regarding the share paths.

Based on the further discussions, the actual requirement is to run VSTest in a container agent environment, whose tests are written in a way that they access some dependencies from a hardcoded network share path.
As far as I tested, the VSTest pipeline task itself doesn't support such scenario to authenticate access to a network share path before executing the tests.
However, since we can use PowerShell script to authenticate access to that share path, I am thinking if we can run vstest in the same PowerShell session.
stages:
- stage: 
  jobs:
  - job:
    pool:
      name: myPool
    container: myContainerResource

    steps:

    - powershell: |   # First Powershell task
        whoami   # This is printed as 'user manager\containeradministrator'

        net use \\share-path\folder1$ /user:$env:ACCOUNT $env:PASSWORD

        if (Test-Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue \\share-path\folder1$)
        {
            Write-Host "Mapping \\mr-fs01\midas$ finished successfully"  # This is executed
        }
        else
        {
          Write-Host "Mapping failed"
          exit 1
        }
        
        gc \\share-path\folder1$\myFile.txt  # The content of the file is accessible and printed

        cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\"  # The location in the container where vstest.console.exe tool is installed
        .\vstest.console.exe "$(Build.SourceDirectory)\DotNetCore\DotNetCoreTests\bin\Debug\net7.0\DotNetCoreTests.dll" # Use vstest.console.exe to test the assemblies (dotnet tests in my case)
      env:
        ACCOUNT: $(USER_SECRET_FROM_VAR_GROUP_KEY_VAULT)
        PASSWORD: $(PWD_SECRET_FROM_VAR_GROUP_KEY_VAULT)


Thanks, while this works, I was wondering if Azure Pipelines supports anything similar to mapping volumes when using container resources, specifically for network shares...

Hi osim_ans, Thanks a lot for your update and I am so curious about your opinion as well. But sorry that I am not so familiar with docker as DevOps and lack the share path environment protected by password. May I ask if you happen to know the docker command to create a container with volumes mounted to share-path with authentication information passed?

If yes, you may test using the options property of the container resource to pass more arguments to container at startup. See Container Jobs in Azure Pipelines

It's possible to map a shared path as a drive, such as drive Q as example, and then use that drive by mapping it as a volume in a container. This can be achieved using the volumes parameter in the container resource. However, directly mapping a network share as a volume is not supported based on what I am seeing...

I agree. I also checked some other discussions on how to mount docker container with volume to a share path. It seemed that we just can't. Since pipeline contain job also uses docker command to startup a container, I am afraid there is nothing we can do from the perspective of Azure DevOps.

Good day @osim_ans, So may I know if you could use the script to run VSTest as a workaround right?

Thanks, it worked. However, then I need to run it for every subsequent task, which is really not a good idea. I think this issue is expected. I noticed that when I manually create a container, run docker exec command, and then run the map share command, exiting the command prompt and re-entering via exec, the shared paths are no longer mapped. Thus this also appears in the pipeline. Not sure if Azure DevOps could provide out-of-the-box support for network share paths.

Hi there,  if it was not supported by docker, I am afraid there is nothing we can do when starting up Azure DevOps container job with docker command.
